# R incorrectly using all CPU cores in matrix multiplication

Tags: r

I recently switched to Linux (fedora) with a new machine and tried to use R for some simulation. But when I tried to do the matrix multiplication, R incorrectly utilizes all CPU cores/threads to the computation even without me setting up the parallel computation. All the CPU cores/threads immediately crank up to 100% once I run the `%*%` code.

For example, when I run following code:

```
N <- 20000
A <- matrix(0.1, nrow = N, ncol = N)
B <- matrix(0.1, nrow = N, ncol = N)
AB <- A %*% B
```

CPU usage of all cores/threads will go up to 100% while executing the `%*%` part.

This causes a huge issue for me, since I would like to further parallelize the simulation by myself. For example, even if I set only using 4 cores to run the simulation with `foreach`, once the code reaches the part of `%*%`, all my 16 threads crank up to 100% and my simulation just couldn't proceed. Followings are the simulation example I would like to run:

```
library(doParallel)
library(foreach)
N <- 10000
A <- matrix(0.1, nrow = N, ncol = N)
B <- matrix(0.1, nrow = N, ncol = N)
cl <- makeCluster(4)
registerDoParallel(cl)
res <- foreach(i = 1:10) %dopar% {
  AB <- A %*% B
  return(list(i = i, AB = AB))
}
stopCluster(cl)
```

This sample code will very likely stuck at the very first 4 iterations, and the CPU usage for all my 8 cores/16 threads will crank up to 100% even I only set using 4 threads.

Followings are my computer spec and R environment

- Fedora 38 with kernel 6.4.15
- R version 4.3.1
- Laptop with AMD Ryzen 9 6900HS CPU with 8 cores/16 threads
- 40 gigs of Ram

I don't have this issue either from my previous machine with Windows or Ubuntu server. They both only use 1 thread while doing the matrix multiplication. I reinstall R, and even reinstall the system (but still fedora since my other works are better on this OS), still no luck of fixing it. Therefore, I am wondering if there is a way to set it back to using fewer cores so I can parallelize the entire simulation by myself later. Thank you for your help!

Comment: Option 1: Use a different (single-threaded) BLAS/LAPACK implementation if you do not like that Fedora gave you a performant one.  Option 2: Use the availble throttles to dial core use down to your liking.  Bost options are documented.